# Stacking Container onto TabBarView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have specific question. I want to stack the Container on top of TabBarView. Is it possible? At the moment, it overlaps onto the TabBar. It should stay persistent (stay in one place) when scrolling left and right through tabs. At the moment, I have something like this. I stacked them one onto other, but the container (in yellow for demonstration purposes) overlaps and goes over TabBar:

```
body: Stack(children: [
        Container(
          height: 50.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
          color: Colors.yellow,
        ),
        TabBarView(
          children: [
            _displayOne(),
            _displayTwo(),
          ],
        ),
      ]),
```

Here is how it looks when it overlaps:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

But you should put it into DefaultTabController widget to make the TabBarView works.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('title'),
      ),
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Stack(children: [
          Container(
            height: 50.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
            color: Colors.yellow,
          ),
          TabBarView(
            children: [
              Center(child: Text('Hello')),
              Center(child: Text('Welcome')),
            ],
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]     [image]

.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, seems not to work, added how it looks like in the original post. It still seems to overlap even though I put it in the tab controller.

Comment: I can't understand what do you mean by "overlap" 
what do you want to do?
Do you and the tab view be under the container or do you want the container be at the background for the tab bar view ?

Comment: I added an image of what will happen when you delete the center widget
Is that what you want?